# Modify regex capturing group in column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, replace

How can I modify the capturing group in pandas `df.replace()`? I try to add thousands separators to the numbers within the string of each cell. This should happen in a method chain. Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a_column': ['1000 text', 'text', '25000 more text', '1234567', 'more text'],
        "b_column": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df = (df.reset_index()
      .replace({"a_column": {"(\d+)": r"\1"}}, regex=True))
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do something with `r"\1"`, e.g., `str(float(r"\1"))` doesn't work.

Expected output:

```
   index         a_column  b_column
0      0        1,000 text       1
1      1            text         2
2      2  25,000 more text       3
3      3        1,234,567        4
4      4        more text        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` in your pipe, looking for a point preceded by a digit and followed by some multiple of 3 digits using this regex:

```
(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)
```

That can then be replaced by a comma (`,`).

```py
df = (df
    .reset_index()
    .replace({ 'a_column' : { r'(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)' : ',' } }, regex=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   index               a_column  b_column
0      0             1,000 text         1
1      1                   text         2
2      2       25,000 more text         3
3      3              1,234,567         4
4      4              more text         5
5      5  563 and 45 and 9 text         6
```

Note I added an extra row to your df to show that you don't get commas where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and match group:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a_column': ['1000 text', 'text', '25000 more text', '1234567', 'more text'],
        "b_column": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

def add_commas(text):
    def format_number(match):
        return "{:,}".format(int(match.group()))
    return re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', format_number, text)

df.a_column.apply(add_commas)
```

outputs:

```
0          1,000 text
1                text
2    25,000 more text
3           1,234,567
4           more text
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```py
df["a_column"] = df["a_column"].str.replace(
    r"\b\d+\b", lambda g: f"{int(g.group(0)):,}", regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           a_column  b_column
0        1,000 text         1
1              text         2
2  25,000 more text         3
3         1,234,567         4
4         more text         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just capturing a group is not enough; we need to manipulate the captured value as well, which means we need a function as a replacer. But `DataFrame.replace` doesn't accept a function while `str.replace` does. However, since you want to use it in a method chain, we could use `assign` here. Basically, add thousands separators and assign the column back to the same column label. So you can try the following (this is essentially the same as the other answers):

```py
(
    df
    .reset_index()
    .assign(a_column=df['a_column'].str.replace(r"(\d+)", lambda g: f"{int(g[1]):,}", regex=True))
)
```

which outputs

```
   index          a_column  b_column
0      0        1,000 text         1
1      1              text         2
2      2  25,000 more text         3
3      3         1,234,567         4
4      4         more text         5
```